# Grouping all equal objects in List without overriding equals method

Tags: java

I have a `List` of some Objects . I have to group all equal objects of list.
Here I don't have to override `euals()` method. (It is already overriden for another functionality)

Please help me.

Comment: Wait, are you saying you cannot use `equals()` to find equal items? Your equals is wrong then.

Comment: Maybe you can pass with a simple `Comparator` and sort the list, it will group equal objects of the list so that they are consecutive. Is this waht you're looking for?

Comment: I've down-voted because you've shown zero evidence of prior research and effort on your part.

Comment: If you override `equals()` you have to override `hashCode()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell the objects are equal without overriding the equals() method unless you want to have the default equals behavior from the Object class. And when you say objects are equal then they should also have the same hashcode.